# How to [MySQL] select users with records

Tags: mysql

I have these tables:

**users**:

```
|user_id|user_name|
|-------|---------|
|   1   |  John   |
|-------|---------|
|   2   |  Mark   |
|-------|---------|
|   3   |  Paul   |
|-------|---------|
```

**records**:

```
| record_id | user_id |    records   |
|-----------|---------|--------------|
|    1      |    3    | lorem ipsum  |
|-----------|---------|--------------|
|    2      |    3    | dolor sit    |
|-----------|---------|--------------|
|    3      |    3    | consectetur  |
|-----------|---------|--------------|
|    4      |    1    | adipisicing  |
|-----------|---------|--------------|
|    5      |    3    | eiusmod      |
|-----------|---------|--------------|
|    6      |    1    | consectetur  |
|-----------|---------|--------------|
```

What I want is to select users who have records. In this case, only ***John*** and ***Paul*** should return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a subquery:

```
SELECT user_name FROM users WHERE user_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM records)
```

Or using an INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT u.user_name FROM users u
INNER JOIN records r ON u.user_id=r.user_id
GROUP BY u.user_name
```

Comment: Let's say I have thousands of records, which of the two performs better?

Comment: Thousands of users, records, or both? JOIN's tend to be faster than subqueries, but in this particular situation my hunch would be the subquery.... In reality there are a lot of factors and you just need to test it both ways and see which is faster for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT u.user_name, r.records FROM users as u, records as r where u.user_id = r.user_id
```